# Consume retrofit rest in Android: call.enqueue error

Tags: android, web-services, call, retrofit

I'm new to  android programming and webservices. To mke this code I used several tutorials, and now I'm a bit lost. The program returns no errors, but it cannot resolve symbol call here:

```
 Call<Void> corretor = service.inserirCorretor(cr);


        call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Fail.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

Also, in the part

```
 if (response.body()) {
```

boolean i required, java.lang.Void is found.
What am I doing wrong? I gave up of this code months ago, now I'm trying it again and still can't find my mistake.

Comment: Response.body() gave you server's response, and you told retrofit that response is void in CallBack. what's the server response ?

Comment: Please post the expected response object from the webservice.

Comment: I guess I didn't code a response, and I can't find the tutorial I used anymore... I was searching for a solution, and found Firebase. Is Firebase useful for this? I just need to add clients and offers, and match them in a search so I know what to offer to any client. But I need this info to be on web, not on SQLite. Firebase will do it? I was using webservice + mysql